# Error with c:if in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, cifs

In my JSP code is written as:

```
<c:if test="${orderListForm.enabledPrevious}">
```

And I am getting following error

```
Testing.jsp:11:7: Static attribute must be a String literal, its illegal to specify an expression.
<c:if test="${orderListForm.enabledPrevious}">
      ^--^
```

What could be the reason? It was working earlier now it is not

Comment: What is data type of `enabledPrevious`? What is `orderListForm`? Is it ArrayList?

Comment: Are you sure `orderListForm.enabledPrevious` results in `boolean` value?

Comment: `orderListForm` is a FormBean and extends `ActionForm`

Comment: I m now getting this error

`03 Feb 2014 08:31:41 |   ERROR | [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] | org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag | ServletException in '/bodyAction.do': Failed to compile JSP /jsp/Testing.jsp

Testing.jsp:5:5: No tag library could be found with this URI. Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there were errors during parsing of the .tld file.
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>`